# What's the difference between Java 8 and Java 7 related to generic methods in type parameter bound?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7

```
public class GenMethodDemo2 {
    static <T, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y){
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (x.equals(y[i])) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Integer[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
        if(isIn("java",nums)) System.out.println("java is in nums");
        if(!isIn("java",nums)) System.out.println("java is not in nums");
    }
}
```

when i use jdk8 this code running well, and result is `java is not in nums`

but when i change to jdk7 the same code will not complie, and the prompt msg is `Inferred type 'java.lang.Integer' for type parameter 'V' is not within its bound; should extend 'java.lang.String'`

i want to know: how jdk8 can complie this code, when the funcation explicit define type parameter bound `V extends T`?

Comment: How is it not running well on jdk7?

Comment: @Thilo sorry, strArray is in the test(){  String[] strArray = {"hello","java","is","well"};  }

Comment: And what is the problem you get on Java 7?

Comment: Can there be a difference in which version of library is imported with different JDK versions?

Comment: @ernest_k  i'm sorry about ask question forgot add clearly error msg, i changed it hope to clarify the mistake

Comment: @Holger yes, `strArray` is a mistake, and i changed the question, hope that was clarified

Comment: @Thilo hi, `strArray` is a mistake, and i changed the question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signature like

```
static <T, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y)
```

is not much better than

```
static boolean isIn(Object x, Object[] y)
```

as the caller can always use `Object` for `T` which allows an arbitrary object as first argument, as well as an arbitrary reference type for the array’s elements.

Hence, when you change the method to

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Integer[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
    if(GenMethodDemo2.<Object,Integer>isIn("java",nums))
            System.out.println("java is in nums");
    if(!GenMethodDemo2.<Object,Integer>isIn("java",nums))
            System.out.println("java is not in nums");
}
```

it can be compiled in all Java versions which support Generics.

Due to the covariant arrays, it would also work to specify

```
if(GenMethodDemo2.<Object,Object>isIn("java",nums))
        System.out.println("java is in nums");
if(!GenMethodDemo2.<Object,Object>isIn("java",nums))
        System.out.println("java is not in nums");
```

Java 8’s type inference does not change which method invocation is valid, it only makes it easier to perform the valid invocations, as you have less scenarios where you need to specify type arguments explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your help, when i go through your answer, it looks like java8 is more humanized design

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are some improvements in type inference for generic methods in Java 8 compared to Java 7, though I am not sure it would explain the difference you are seeing. In any case, when inference fails, you can always explicitly provide a type witness to prove to the compiler that there exists a type where the bounds will be met, like:

```
if (GenMethodDemo2.<Object, Integer>isIn("java",nums))
    System.out.println("java is in nums");
```

In this case, both type variables `T` and `V` can always be chosen to be `Object`, and it won't accept any fewer set of parameters (since any `T` will be a subtype of `Object` and any `V[]` will be a subtype of `Object[]`). So your method doesn't actually need any generics:

```
static boolean isIn(Object x, Object[] y){
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (x.equals(y[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help, with you answer, i realized java8 is much more smarter